# Problem in inserting data in SQLite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

Hi i am using FMDB to retrieve data from SQLITE database.

```
db  = [[FMDatabase alloc] initWithPath:path];   
[db open];  
FMResultSet *fResult= [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM Users"];

aUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while([fResult next])
{
    userData = [fResult stringForColumn:@"Name"];       
    lblUsers.text=[lblUsers.text  stringByAppendingString:userData];
    [aUsers addObject:userData];        
    NSLog(@"The data is %@=",userData);
}   
[db close];
[aUsers release];
[db release];
```

So i got output to this program is

**Sachin Rahul Dravid**

But when i try to insert data to the databse,
i used the following coding

```
   [db beginTransaction];
[db executeUpdate:@"insert into users (name) values('Balaji R')" ,nil];
[db commit];
```

Now i again retrieve the data from database.
So i got a output like this

**Sachin Rahul Dravid Balaji R**

But when i quit my application and then bulid it again,
Now i am seeing only the old records

**Sachin Rahul Dravid**

The inserted recorded "Balaji R" gone away!

Anybody know where i did the mistake?Please tell me the solution......

Comment: I've worked with SQLite in VisualStudio, and every time I do a build, it copies the SQLite database file from the resources folder to the bin folder. This means every build/execute will start with the same base version of the db and changes made to the database during one debugging session don't persist to the next. Not sure if you're experiencing the same phenomenon...

Comment: what is the value of `path`?
executeUpdate returns a `BOOL` check the return value.
The `,nil` after the SQL string is unnecessary

Comment: path value is /Users/balajir/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.0.1/Applications/7E4DB460-41B2-4AD4-B80C-7E4735104C15/DBTesting.app/MyDataNew.sql

executeUpdate returns "YES".

Is there any way to persist the data in database?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to write to the app bundle directory which is not allowed. You have to copy your starting database to the user's Documents directory and pass the path of the copy to the `FMDB initWithPath:` Take a look at the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW6). Take a look at the [CoreDataBooks](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Listings/Classes_CoreDataBooksAppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405-Classes_CoreDataBooksAppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_8) sample code. The App Delegate has code in the `persistentStoreCoordinator` method that you can use as a guide for your implementation.